# Thread timeout when stopping TIdTCPServer

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

When I´m trying to stop my TIdTCPServer I´m getting a EIdTerminateThreadTimeout. I guess it´s because the client side of the connection is not closed.

I´m a bit lost working with Indy, what´s the proper way to stop all the threads created by the server? Is there any particular order in which I should stop the threads, clear the bindings and toggle off the Active flag?

This is my clean-up code for the server side

```
procedure TPassiveConnection.StopServer;
begin
    { Si el servidor ya está a la escucha es porque me he suscrito
    de forma satisfactoria en el gateway  }
    if( ListenerServer.Active ) then
    begin
        SendUnsubscribeMessage();
    end;

    ListenerServer.Active := false;

    ListenerServer.Bindings.Clear;
end;
```

I get the EIdTerminateThreadTimeout after setting the Active flag.

This are the server handlers

```
{ Se ha abierto la conexión }
procedure TPassiveConnection.tsConnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
    AnotarMensaje(odDepurar, 'Recibida conexión entrante' );
end;

{
    Este manejador se invoca cada vez que se ponen datos en el socket
    Se leen esos datos y se invoca el comando enviado
}
procedure TPassiveConnection.tsExecute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
    Command: string;
begin
    Command := AThread.Connection.ReadLn;
    if Command <> '' then
    begin
        ExecuteRemoteCommand( Command );
    end;
end;

{ Se ha cerrado la conexión }
procedure TPassiveConnection.tsDisconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
    AnotarMensaje(odDepurar, 'Cerrando puerto de escucha' );
    AThread.Connection.Disconnect;
    AThread.Terminate();
end;

{ Se ha producido un error durante la conexión }
procedure TPassiveConnection.tsException(AThread: TIdPeerThread; AException: Exception);
begin
    AnotarMensaje(odDepurar, 'Excepción capturada en conexión entrante' + AException.Message );
end;
```

I tried calling the Terminate method in the disconnect handler but I keep getting the Exception.

Comment: The timeout means a client thread is most likely deadlocked and not terminating at all. What do `AnotarMensaje()` and `ExecuteRemoteCommand()` look like? Are they thread-safe? As for the `OnDisconnect` event, it is fired when a client thread is in progress of being stopped, so there is no need to call `Disconnect()` or `Terminate()` in it.

Comment: Thanks, Remy! I found out that my problem was there, on the tsExecute.